# How to display the index of element in a list

Tags: c#

I'm new to and currently learning C#, and I have to write a console application where the user inputs a list of, let's say, books, but it's a list of classes. Let's say I have this class called Books.

```
class Books
{
    public string name;
    public string description;
    public double price;
```

And now I create a list with type `Books`

```
List<Books> myBooks = new List<Books>();
```

And that I ask the user to add the books:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= s; x++)
{
    Books newbook = new Books();
    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease input the name, description and price of the book:\n");
    newbook.name = Console.ReadLine();
    newbook.description = Console.ReadLine();
    newbook.price = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    myBooks.Add(newbook);
    //Displaying what the user just entered
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}: {2}. Price: {3}", /*add index*/, newbook.name, newbook.description, newbook.price);
}
```

As you can see, I needed something to display in which part of the list the book is in, for each one of them (books).

I tried using, `myBooks.Count()` and `myBooks[x]`, but those returned either the same value (because of the size of the list) or just `[namespace.class]`. Is there a solution (in an integer form, it can be zero based too) that doesn't involve adding another class or creating another variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not use your loop variable x?

Comment: @FrankM because it has nothing to do with the index of a book in a list.

Comment: @koryakinp well if the list was empty at the beginning x is the index of the newly added book... I missed that the list could contain elements at the start, so thx for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the index of the most recently added item, you can use `(myBooks.Count() - 1)`.

Alternatively, you could store the value returned from `myBooks.Count()` *before* you add the item, and that value will be the index where the item will be added.

Finally, in your test example, you could've also used the value of `x`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried using `x` to display the index of certain book, but I needed the user then to choose which book they want from that list.

Comment: @ChrisJ.: So doesn't that answer your question then?

Comment: How can the `x` be linked to the list? Like, does it need to be inside the class to be linked to the books?

Comment: @ChrisJ.: Can I suggest you read my answer? I only made a comment about `x` at the very end. Is there a language barrier here? (And `x` is linked to the list because you add one item for each time through the loop.) I'll just assume you didn't read what I wrote.

Comment: I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an indexed collection just use an array :

```
int totalBooks = 25;
Books[] myBooks = new Books[totalBooks]; // 25 is the number of books an the indexes are from 0 to 24
for (int i = 0; i < totalBooks; i++)
{
    Books newbook = new Books();
    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease input the name, description and price of the book {0} :\n", (i+1));
    newbook.name = Console.ReadLine();
    newbook.description = Console.ReadLine();
    newbook.price = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    myBooks[i] = newbook;
    //Displaying what the user just entered
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}: {2}. Price: {3}", (i+1), newbook.name, newbook.description, newbook.price);
}
```

Comment: No, `List` is *not* implemented as a linked list. There is a `LinkedList` class for that. `List` can be indexed just like an array.

Comment: @JonathanWood you're right, sorry. I updated the answer.

Comment: So, in your update, the index would be `i` (not `i + 1`). And also it would work the same with a `List`.

Comment: `i` will be from 0 to 24 inside the loop, `(i+1)` will be from 1 to 25 which I think what the guy wanted in the first place (display purposes).

Comment: @JonathanWood: Agree with your first comment, but the `i+1` is arguably better. End users generally don't like to work with 0-based indexes. He's only using `i+1` in cases of output, not when accessing the array.

Comment: Well, okay. He said he wanted the index in the title. He also said it could be zero based so I guess he's fine with it being 1-based. Would still work with a list though.

Answer (score 0):

You'll use the [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx) method on the list

```
myBooks.Add(newbook);
//Displaying what the user just entered
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}: {2}. Price: {3}", myBooks.IndexOf(newbook), 
     newbook.name, newbook.description, newbook.price);
```

I don't see why `myBooks.Count()` wouldn't also work, because you're inserting at the end of the list, but the most descriptive method is using `IndexOf`.

Side note: your class `Books` describes a book; general practice is name a class after a singular object. You might want to rename that to `Book` for simplicity or clarity.